# Find string in other string and if succesful show searched string(s)

Tags: r, string, search, keyword

I have a list of products (500.000+) and want to search a column to match certain keywords (5.000+). In the end I want to have only those products/lines left which contain at least one of these searchterm. Could also be multiple ones per product. I managed to just filter down to the required data, BUT I also want to have a column where I see WHY it has been selected as this is not obvious in every case (with 5.000+ searchterms). The final code should run on a standard laptop (core I5,16 GB RAM).

**#Example data**

```
SearchTerms2<-c("Lamborghini|Ferrari")

df<-data.frame(LineCode = c(1:7),
               Product = c("Lamborghini Urus & Ferrari Purosangue", "Ferrari 
Purosangue","Lamborghini Huracan","Skoda Rapid","Skoda Kodiaq","Audi A6 Avant","Lamborghini 
Urus"))

dffilterd <- filter(df,grepl(SearchTerms2,df$Product))
```

**#Desired outcome:**

```
1;Lamborghini Urus & Ferrari Purosangue;Lamborghini/Ferrari

2;Ferrari Purosangue;Ferrari

3;Lamborghini Huracan;Lamborghini

7;Lamborghini Urus;Lamborghini
```

At the moment I can only imagine a really large table with 500.000+ lines & 5.000+ columns and running some function over the whole table, but I assume this will be waste of memory + not the fastest solution for a problem like this.

Comment: Even if you manage to avoid creating a 500.000 x 5000 table, the regexp approach implies at least  500.000 x 5.000 regexp operations. What if you try to tokenize the df products and match it directly? I'll try to write something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution that uses `tokenizers` to separate words in Product. This way does not depends on grep every match. I use data.table for speed given the huge dataframe you have.

```
library(tokenizers)
library(data.table)

searchTerms <- c("Lamborghini","Ferrari")

df<-data.frame(LineCode = c(1:7),Product = c(
    "Lamborghini Urus & Ferrari Purosangue",
    "Ferrari Purosangue","Lamborghini Huracan","Skoda Rapid",
    "Skoda Kodiaq","Audi A6 Avant","Lamborghini Urus"))
setDT(df)
setkey(df, LineCode)

df_tokens <- df[, .(words=tolower(unique(tokenize_words(Product, simplify = T)))), 
                by=LineCode]
searchTerms <- tolower(searchTerms)
df_tokens<- df_tokens[words %in% searchTerms, .(matches=paste(words, collapse="/")),
                keyby = LineCode]

df_tokens <- df_tokens[df, .(LineCode, Product, matches), on = "LineCode"]

df_tokens
#> Key: <LineCode>
#>    LineCode                               Product             matches
#>       <int>                                <char>              <char>
#> 1:        1 Lamborghini Urus & Ferrari Purosangue lamborghini/ferrari
#> 2:        2                    Ferrari Purosangue             ferrari
#> 3:        3                   Lamborghini Huracan         lamborghini
#> 4:        4                           Skoda Rapid                <NA>
#> 5:        5                          Skoda Kodiaq                <NA>
#> 6:        6                         Audi A6 Avant                <NA>
#> 7:        7                      Lamborghini Urus         lamborghini
```

Comment: Also i use `tolower` to prevent problems with the letter case. But you can omit it if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply on my problem. It is a great solution as it is extremly fast also on big datasets. I realized now, by using your approach, that I also have cases where I have 2 words within a string & want to search for the whole expression, e.g.  like in my example it would be something like "Ferrari Purosangue". Do you see a way to modify the code accordingly? I fear the step which splits the original string into single words is an issue for these cases...

Comment: For example, for one or two word search it could be useful to use `tokenize_ngrams(Product, n_min= 1, n = 2, simplify=T)` instead of `tokenize_words`
Of course, if you problem is more complex than matching simple consecutive words, you will end in the `grepl` approach for each item.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution helped me solving the problem in a real efficient way!